# On Simpson method

Tags: integration

Hi  I have a question about Simpson method , can someone explain me why when we use Simpson method for an equation of second degree we divide the domain by 2 only ? and when it's cubic we divide by 3 ? What is the reason behind that ?

Answer (score -1):

The general polynom of degree 2 has 3 coefficients, that of degree 3 has 4 coefficients. Accordingly you need that number of points to define the according polynomial curve of according degree. - As you will connect several such finite parts of these curves, you will have the continuity relation as well (last point of former = first point of next). This reduces the number of points per interval by 1.

--- rk